# Html.DevExpress().HtmlEditor - How to pass to controller's action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi I have a htmleditor like this:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@Html.DevExpress().HtmlEditor(
settings =>
{
settings.Name = "heFeatures";
settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "HtmlEditor", Action = "FeaturesPartial" };
settings.SettingsImageUpload.UploadCallbackRouteVa lues = new { Controller = "HtmlEditor", Action = "FeaturesImageUpload" };
settings.SettingsImageSelector.Enabled = true;
settings.SettingsImageSelector.EditingSettings.All owCreate = true;
settings.SettingsImageSelector.EditingSettings.All owDelete = true;
settings.SettingsImageSelector.EditingSettings.All owMove = true;
settings.SettingsImageSelector.EditingSettings.All owRename = true;
settings.SettingsImageSelector.UploadSettings.Enab led = true;
}).GetHtml()
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
```

How I can do in htmleditor data send to controllers's method. I need this htmlcontent save to my database...I do this in asp.net web form like this: `editor1.content` in codebehind but I don't know how to do this in Razor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some samples here that might be useful:

http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/98704/337740.aspx